# How To Play Video from HTML5 in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

i want to play video from html 5 file by zipping and unzip file programmatically of this link
http://enhancelearning.co.in/downloads/HTML5.zip 
this file contain 4 html file
zip and unzip successfully created but video not playing in web view
here is th my code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docspath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // NSString *cachePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];



    NSString *zipFile = [docspath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"001.html"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:zipFile];
    [webVew loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try first to put this html file somewhere in the net and see if the video playing when you go to this page from safari.
It's probably HTML-Safari-ios problem, and this way it easier to debug.